# Identity of indiscernibles and relation to the indiscernibility of identity

Tags: logic

Consider Leibniz's principle of the indiscernibility of identity, stated in (1) in second order logic:

$$(1) \hspace{0.3cm} \forall x \thinspace \forall y \thinspace [\hspace{0.2cm}x \hspace{0.2cm}= \hspace{0.2cm}y \hspace{0.2cm} \rightarrow \hspace{0.2cm} \forall P\hspace{0.2cm}(Px \hspace{0.2cm} \leftrightarrow \hspace{0.2cm} Py)]$$

Many axiomatisations of FOL (First Order Logic) seem to contain principles of substitution that amount to a schematic form of this principle in which $(1)$ below holds, for any variables $x$ and $y$ and any formula $\Phi \thinspace(x)$, if $\Phi\thinspace(y)$ is obtained by replacing any number of free occurrences of $x$ in $\Phi$ with $y$, such that these remain free occurrences of $y$:

$$(2) \hspace{0.3cm} x \hspace{0.2cm} = \hspace{0.2cm} y \hspace{0.3cm} \rightarrow  \hspace{0.3cm}[\thinspace \Phi \thinspace(x) \hspace{0.2cm} \leftrightarrow \hspace{0.2cm} \Phi\thinspace(y) \thinspace ] \hspace{0.2cm}$$

Now consider the converse of (1) in second order logic (The identity of indiscernibles):

$$(1') \hspace{0.3cm} \forall x \thinspace  \forall y \thinspace [ \thinspace \forall P \hspace{0.3cm}(Px \hspace{0.3cm} \leftrightarrow \hspace{0.3cm} Py) \hspace{0.3cm} \rightarrow \hspace{0.3cm} x \hspace{0.3cm}= \hspace{0.3cm}y \thinspace ]$$
Can FOL be axiomatised taking the converse of (2) as an axiom?

$$(2') \hspace{0.3cm}[\thinspace \Phi \thinspace(x) \hspace{0.2cm} \leftrightarrow \hspace{0.2cm} \Phi\thinspace(y) \thinspace ] \hspace{0.2cm} \rightarrow  \hspace{0.3cm} x \hspace{0.2cm} = \hspace{0.2cm} y\hspace{0.2cm}$$

More generally, how is $(2')$, for an arbitrary predicate $\Phi$, derivable in FOL?

---

Noah Schweber has pointed out that $(2')$ is false in FOL. But how about $(2'')$:

$$(2'') \hspace{0.3cm}\forall x \thinspace \forall y \hspace{0.3cm} [\thinspace[\thinspace \Phi \thinspace(x) \hspace{0.2cm} \leftrightarrow \hspace{0.2cm} \Phi\thinspace(y) \thinspace ] \hspace{0.2cm} \rightarrow  \hspace{0.3cm} x \hspace{0.2cm} = \hspace{0.2cm} y\hspace{0.2cm}]$$

How is $(2'')$ derivable for arbitrary $\Phi$ in FOL? I suppose it would again be falsified in the empty structures Noah mentioned?

If not, can FOL be axiomatised taking the (2'') as an axiom?
More generally, what is the status of the identity of indiscernibles in FOL?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, (2') is **false** in first-order logic. Consider, for example, a two-element structure $\{a, b\}$ in the empty language. Then $a$ and $b$ satisfy all the same sentences, but $a\not=b$.

(Note that if we allow *parameters* in $\Phi$, then identity of indiscernibles holds for a silly reason: $a$ satisfies "$x=a$," but any $b\not=a$ will not.)

And, in fact, the [patterns of indiscernibility](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pl/1235414202) within a structure can be extremely complicated, and are important in model theory; see also [this previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/50305/use-of-indiscernibles-in-model-theory).

Comment: Thank you :). I have edited my question, for a puzzle remains... :)

Comment: Outside of the empty language is $(2')$ true?

Comment: @Lukelindenbaum No, there are examples in any language - e.g. given a structure $\mathcal{M}$ in an arbitrary language, we can form the "disjoint union" $\mathcal{M}\sqcup \mathcal{M}$ consisting of two copies of $\mathcal{M}$ side-by-side (strictly speaking, this only works if the language consists only of relation and constant symbols; with function symbols it's a bit messier). Now every element of $\mathcal{M}$ corresponds to a pair of indiscernibles, one in each copy of $\mathcal{M}$. (cont'd)

Comment: And (2'') fails for exactly the same reason. There really isn't any way around it: **identity of indiscernibles fails in first-order logic.**

Comment: But it the identity of indiscernibles IS provable in SOL on the full semantics, correct? I'm confused by whether it is provable in the Henkin semantics because Thomas Klimpel's answer here seems to contradict Peter Smith's answer (Thomas Klimpel presents a proof of the principle, whereas Peter Smith says such a proof is not possible): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353353/monadic-second-order-logic-without-constants-functions-and-equality

Comment: @Lukelindenbaum You're conflating two different notions of "indiscernible." The sentence "$\forall x, y(\forall P(P(x)\iff P(y))\iff x=y)$" (call it "$*$") is true in second-order logic. However, remember *why* $*$ is true: it's because given any $x=a$, we can take $P=\{a\}$, and then any $y$ satisfies $P(y)$ iff $y=a$. But this set $P$ is not definable (in general) without reference to $a$! If we look only at predicates which are *definable without parameters*, then identity of indiscernibles fails for second-order logic as well. (cont'd)

Comment: Note that it's really this second version that more faithfully captures Leibnitz' philosophical idea: admitting arbitrary predicates "$x=a$" kind of assumes that we already have the ability to identify arbitrary elements, so identity of indiscernibles holds vacuously in this way. The interesting case is when we restrict attention to predicates which are *expressible* (e.g. definable without parameters) - and this version fails even in second-order logic

Comment: (Also, you shouldn't say "provable in second-order logic" - second-order logic with the standard semantics does not have a reasonable proof system.)

Comment: :) Also, what is the relationship between the axiom of extensionality in ZFC and the identity of indiscernibles? They seem awfully similar to me...

Comment: @Lukelindenbaum You can think of extensionality as a special kind of identity of indiscernibles. For each $a$, let $P_a$ be the property "contains $a$". Then extensionality says that for all $x$ and $y$, $$\forall a(P_a(x)\iff P_a(y))\iff x=y.$$ (Note that this is a version of the *weak* kind of IOI as per my comment above - the predicates "$P_a$" are defined with parameters.)

Comment: In Henkin's "Completeness in the land of types", p.83 http://www.jstor.org/stable/2266967?seq=3#page_scan_tab_contents     axiom 10 is the principle of extensionality. However, it is not clear to me that he is using the weak form of extensionality that you mention. I am a little confused here.

Comment: @Lukelindenbaum I never described a weak form of extensionality. There's only one kind of extensionality, which I said could be viewed as a weak version of IOI - in between the strong kind of IOI which fails in first-order logic, and the weak kind of IOI which holds in second-order logic. As to what Henkin's writing, it's difficult for me to follow since I'm not familiar with the notation of type theory, but it looks like the second part of A10 is extensionality for functions - "two functions which agree on all inputs are identical" - and the first is an "atomic" extensionality.

Comment: I want to reiterate the point I made above, because I think it's the most germane to this question: **identity of indiscernibles fails in first-order logic**. Extensionality is a kind of IOI where we *broaden* the class of allowable properties to include certain properties-with-parameters (namely, of the form $P_a$ as in my answer), and second-order logic (with standard semantics) can express and prove an extremely weak (indeed, trivial in my opinion) kind of IOI - indeed, second-order logic with Henkin semantics, and some basic set axioms, can prove this kind of IOI - (cont'd)

Comment: but this is *far* from the spirit of actual IOI. Once we allow parameters in our properties, IOI becomes trivial. In fact, there's a trivial version of IOI for *first*-order logic: for an element $a$ of a model $M$, consider the property (defined with a parameter for $a$) $E_a(x)$="$x=a$". Clearly $a$ has this property, and clearly any other element with this property is in fact $a$. (Since first-order logic can't discuss sets directly, we need to view properties as formulas, and properties-with-parameters as formulas-with-parameters.) IOI is trivial with parameters, and false without them.